# Find Circumdiameter of Δ HBC.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

If H is the orthocenter of an acute angled ΔABC whose circumcircle is $x^2+y^2=16$, then circumdiameter of the triangle HBC is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** The reflection of $H$ in $BC$ lies on the circumcircle of $\triangle ABC$. What does this say about the reflection of the circumcircle in $BC$?

Comment: I know that fact but it does'nt helps in solving for the circumdiameter of HBC

Comment: The fact that the circumcircles of $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle BHC$ are reflections of eachother in $BC$, implies that they have equal circumradius.

Answer (score 2):

By the sine theorem, the circumradius is given by:
$$ R = \frac{a}{2\sin A}. $$
Since $\widehat{BHC}=\pi-\widehat{HBC}-\widehat{HCB}=\widehat{B}+\widehat{C}=\pi-\widehat{A}$, the circumradius of $BHC$ is the same as the circumradius of $ABC$.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Let O and I be the circum-centers of ⊿ABC and ⊿HBC respectively. HD HE and HF are perpendicular to BC, BA and AC respectively.

The red line is the line of centers and the purple line (BC) is the common chord. In addition, BC is perpendicularly bisected at K.

For some reasons, the brown (AEHF) and green (BHCJ) quadrilaterals are cyclic.

We have the following relations:-
$$\angle BOC = 2 \angle A = 2 \angle FHB = 2 \angle J = \angle BIC.$$

Using all of the above information, we can conclude that OBIC is a rhombus.

Thus, the circum-diameter of ⊿HBC is the same that of ⊿ABC.